# What are some good resources to study Cryptography?

Tags: cryptography

What are some good resources to study Cryptography?

I have knowledge of abstract algebra .Is it enough to take up Cryptography as a special paper or I will have to undergo courses in some other topics.

Also I want to know some books other than Stinson in this regard.

Can someone here help me if this is the right topic for me to choose and what are the current research scopes in this regard and what are the application of this topic.

Comment: How much do you know already?

Comment: You might be in luck. This Coursera course on cryptography started last week, and there's still time to catch up: https://www.coursera.org/course/crypto

Comment: If you enjoy abstract algebra, Koblitz's books *Algebraic Aspects of Cryptography* and *A Course in Number Theory and Cryptography* might be interesting to you.

Answer (score 2):

If you are from mathematics background, then **Introduction to Mathematical Cryptography** by **Silverman** etal is good. However for a more formal approach, **Introduction to Modern Cryptography** by **Jonathan Katz** and **Yehuda Lindell**, 2nd edition by CRC press is a nice textbook. If you are from Computer science background, **Foundations of Cryptography** by **Oded Goldreich** should be the starting point.

Comment: You are welcome.